# Expected value of $X+Y$

Tags: probability, expectation

Why does $E[X+Y]$ equal the following?:

$$\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \sum_{x,y}(x+y)P(X=x,Y=y)$$

I dont understand why its a joint probability instead of $P(X=x+Y=y)$. Can somebody please make it clear why its a joint probability instead?

Comment: Presumably you mean "instead of $P(X+Y = x + y)$"

Comment: @Ant Yes I did.

Comment: What you wrote out is called "LOTUS" - law of the unconscious statistician. Both forms are equivalent. $E(g(X))=\sum g(x)P(X=x)=\sum xP(g(X)=x)$

Comment: @A.S. Ohhh i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call $Z = X+Y$

$$E(Z) = \sum_z z P(Z=z) = \sum_{x+y} (x +y) P(X+Y = x + y) $$

where the last sum is intended as "all the values the sum $x+y$ can take". It means exactly the same thing as $\sum_z zP(X+Y = z)$, I wrote it that way so to remark the "parallelism" between the two formulas. (Hope it's more clear now with the edit)

The key point though is that these sums I just wrote are over all the possible values of $x+y$

If you instead take a sum on all distinct values of $x$ and $y$ (like you do), then you can "group" together all the elements that result in the same $x + y$, and the your joint probability $P(X = x, Y=y)$ gets summed over all the elements that result in the same $x+y$ resulting in $P(X+Y = x + y)$, same expression as above

Comment: so either P(X+Y,x+y) or P(X=x,Y=y) would work?

Comment: Sorry but $$E(X+Y) \ne \sum_{x,y} (x +y) P(X+Y = x + y) $$ in general. Consider for example $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{0,1\}^2$ then $E(X)=E(Y)=\frac12$ hence $E(X+Y)=1$ while $P(X+Y=0)=\frac14$, $P(X+Y=1)=\frac12$ and $P(X+Y=2)=\frac14$ hence $$\sum_{x=0}^1\sum_{y=0}^1(x +y) P(X+Y = x + y) =(0+0)\tfrac14+(0+1)\tfrac12+(1+0)\tfrac12+(1+1)\tfrac14=\tfrac32.$$ One must choose between $$E(X+Y)=\sum_zzP(X+Y=z)$$ and $$E(X+Y)=\sum_{x,y}(x+y)P(X=x,Y=y).$$

Comment: @Did Yes, that was my point, maybe I did not express myself clearly . But I said that the first sum I wrote (the very first line, second equality) is not summed over all $x,y$ but over all values of $x + y$. Which is equivalent to summing over all $x,y$ but using $P(X=x,Y=y)$ instead

Comment: @ArmonSafai Either would work, depending though of what you sum over! My first sum was actually $\sum_{x + y} (x+y)P(X+Y = x+y)$, meaning not summing over all invidivuals $x,y$ but only on the different values that their sum can take. See also Did's comment for that :-)

Comment: In view of 1. the fact that the present formula in your post is incorrect, and 2. the OP's first comment, let me suggest to disambiguate the formulation in your answer.

Comment: @Did I did, hopefully it's more clear :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the notation $\sum\limits_{x+y}$ is not one that one can recommand... Anyway.

Comment: @Did I get your point, I'll try to avoid it in the future :-)